# Восстановить высоту виджета внутри сплиттера

Tags: qt, qsettings

Мне необходимо восстановить высоту виджетов, которые находятся внутри вертикального сплиттера. 

Пытался сделать при помощи `QSettings` и `restoreGeometry()`, но ничего не изменилось. На всякий случай прикрепляю код:

```
void FirstWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent *event)
{
    QSettings settings("tempName", "firstwidget");
    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
    QWidget::hideEvent(event);
}

void FirstWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    QSettings settings("tempName", "firstwidget");
    restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray());
    QWidget::showEvent(event);
}

void SecondWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent *event)
{
    QSettings settings("tempName", "secondwidget");
    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
    QWidget::hideEvent(event);
}

void SecondWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    QSettings settings("tempName", "secondwidget");
    restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray());
    QWidget::showEvent(event);
}
```

main.cpp

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setOrganizationName("tempName");
```

Так же пробовал сделать `QSettings settings` переменной класса (вдруг раз она локальная, значит удаляется), но роли это не сыграло.

Не знаю, важно это или нет, но `SecondWidget` периодически удаляется и создаётся заново. Делается это при помощи сигналов и слотов, управляющий класс (MainWindow) его не знает. 

Удаление имеет вид

```
delete static_cast<SecondWidget*>(sender() );
```